# CSS add small border bottom to text using selector ::after

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I need to add a small border bottom to my text using the selector `::after`.

```
<h3>
  Hello, this border is too long
</h3>

<h4>
  Hello, this border should be small
</h4>
```

The `<h3>` element has a normal border, which fills the entire space of the text.
But I need the `<h4>` element to only have a border with 10px length.

Basically this is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

So I tried to play a little with CSS without success:

```
h3
{
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
}

h4::after
{
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
  width: 10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qkw37scn/2/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
h3
{
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
}

h4::after
{
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
  width: 10px;
  display: block;
}
```

adding a `display: block;` on your pseudo element will do the trick.

Comment: The above answer will work to show the pseudo-element border, but it won't be sufficient to make it centered as shown in the OP example.

Answer (score 2):

```css
h3
{
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
}
h4{
display : inline-block;
}
h4::after
{
    content: '';
    border-bottom: 8px solid #000;
    width: 52px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<h3>
  Hello, this border is too long
</h3>

<h4>
  Hello, this border should be small
</h4>
```

Answer (score 1):

Making the pseudo-element a block will help place it underneath the text and to get more control you can position it to be relative to move the line around.

```
h4::after
{
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
  width: 10px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do it:

```
h4 {
  display: inline-block;
}

h4::after
{
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
  width: 10px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

But you need the H4 to be an inline-block, otherwise the underline is centered in the container of the H4, not centered in the middle of the text. Making the H4 an inline-block will change a bit the behavior of the H4 though.

**UPDATE:**

If you are allowed to not only change the CSS but the HTML also, this would be a better solution:

```css
h3 > div
{
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
}


h4 > div {
  display: inline-block;
}

h4 > div::after
{
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
  width: 10px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<h3>
  <div>
    Hello, this border is NOT too long
  </div>
</h3>

<h4>
  <div>
    Hello, this border should be small
  </div>
</h4>
```